# Find an element that only has one other kind of child

Tags: xpath

I want to use XPath to find every `<blockquote>` element that has at least one child `<pre>` element, no other kinds of child elements, and optionally text nodes as children:

```
<body><div><!-- arbitrary nesting -->
  <blockquote><pre>YES</pre></blockquote>
  <blockquote><p>NO</p></blockquote>
  <blockquote><pre>NO</pre><p>NO</p></blockquote>
  <blockquote><p>NO</p><pre>NO</pre></blockquote>
  <blockquote><pre>YES</pre> <pre>YES</pre></blockquote>
  <blockquote>NO</blockquote>
</div></body>
```

This XPath appears to work, but I suspect that it's overly complicated:

```
//blockquote[pre][not(*[not(name()="pre")])]
```

Is there a better (less code, more efficient, more DRY) way to select what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//blockquote[* and not(*[not(self::pre)])]
```

This selects all `blockquote` elements in the XML document that have at least one element child and don't have any element child that isn't a `pre` element.

This is just an application of the **[double negation law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation#Double_negation)** :).

Do note, that this expression is more efficient than one that counts all element children (because the selection stops right at the moment a non-`pre` child is found).

**XSLT - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
     <xsl:copy-of select="//blockquote[* and not(*[not(self::pre)])]"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<body><div><!-- arbitrary nesting -->
      <blockquote><pre>YES</pre></blockquote>
      <blockquote><p>NO</p></blockquote>
      <blockquote><pre>NO</pre><p>NO</p></blockquote>
      <blockquote><p>NO</p><pre>NO</pre></blockquote>
      <blockquote><pre>YES</pre> <pre>YES</pre></blockquote>
      <blockquote>NO</blockquote>
</div></body>
```

**the XPath expression is evaluated and the selected nodes are copied to the output:**

```
<blockquote>
   <pre>YES</pre>
</blockquote>
<blockquote>
   <pre>YES</pre>
   <pre>YES</pre>
</blockquote>
```

Answer (score 5):

```
//blockquote[pre][count(pre)=count(*)]
```

Comment: I don't think they're needed.