# Apply style when all childs are the same

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have a rare demand:

I need the style "list-style:none" only when I have `<ol>` childs and no more tags.

Example, in this case I will apply the style:

```
<div>
  <ol><li>1</li></ol>
  <ol><li>2</li></ol>
</div>
```

In each other, I will disable the style:

```
 <div>
  <p>
  <ol><li>1</li></ol>
</div>
```

What is the best way? Thanks

Comment: I don't *think* this is possible in just CSS, for conditional behaviour of this type I'd *think* you'd need to use JavaScript. But I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: haha, impossible is nothing!!

Comment: Lots of things are impossible using purely CSS, and believe this may be one of them. You'd need either JavaScript or something server-side to set different classNames on your <div> tag dependant on the contents.

Comment: How are the list being generated?

Comment: the code is hardcoded :(

Comment: So can't you just hardcode different classes?

Comment: yes! I think this is the only solution :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with pure CSS. You'll have to either modify the HTML to add classes manually, or use a script to determine if there are only `ol` elements inside and no other types of children, then apply the class or the style.

Comment: Interestingly, this is possible with XPath: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438787/find-an-element-that-only-has-one-other-kind-of-child

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
div ol:only-of-type {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Any lists where there is only a single li element should now be styled with no list style.

Only compatible with IE9+ (and all the rest)

Source: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RGnJW/

Comment: Nop, this pseudo-class only works when in have only one <ol> child

Comment: Your description of `:only-of-type` is wrong, and `:only-of-type` won't work here anyway.

Answer (score -1):

You can use following CSS:

```
ol li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Comment: :( this isn't the solution, if your answer will be the solution I don't ask this in stackoverflow